# How to acces variables, from a functions that are inside a class, from the kivy file?

Tags: python, function, class, kivy, kivymd

I know that we can access variables declared in the main class of the app. This can be done using "app.NameOfTheVariable", for example, access to a string value:

```
#Python file
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

class MainScreen(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    App_Name = "Galasken Proyect 001"

MainApp.run()



#Kivy file
MainScreen:
<MainScreen>:
    MDLabel:
       text: app.App_name
```

However, I want to know how can we access variables that are inside a function which is inside a class. For example, in the next code, how can I access to "Object_name"

```
#Python file
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout

class MainScreen(MDBoxLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    App_Name = "App Example"

    def a_function(self):
        Object_name = "this is a name"

MainApp.run()
```

I have tried different things on the kivy file but nothing have workd. These are the things that I have tried:

```
#Kivy file
MainScreen:
<MainScreen>:
    MDLabel:
       text: app.a_function().App_name
     # text: app.a_function.App_name
     # text: app.App_name
```

What can I do to access that variable?

Answer (score 0):

The variable `Object_name` in the function `a_function` is inaccessible to you because it is "local" in the scope of the function.

One thing you can do is:

```
def a_function(self):
    self.Object_name = "this is a name"
```

This will place `Object_name` in the scope of `MainApp` and can be accessed by `app.Object_name`

NB: This could be side-effect-y. The `Object_name` member variable in `MainApp` does not exist until you call `a_function()`. If you try to access `app.Object_name` before calling that function, you'll get an error about the Attribute not existing.

You can stop this side effect by adding `self.Object_name` in your `__init__` constructor method. Alternatively, you can just have `a_function()` return that string directly.

```
def a_function(self):
    Object_name = "this is a name"
    return Object_name
```